# Excel VBA for pulling apart text from a few cells and creating multiple cells of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like someone to suggest the coding in VBA required to convert this data. Essentially B2 and B3 there will be multiple cells like there, even with more ";" and numbers after. The T and I won't change, but some don't always have T or I, they are just a single number.

The final output needs to be B12:C37

I essentially want a list of numbers with the corresponding data next to it. So 1T4 should be 1,2,3,4 in 4 cells (in 1 column), 1T5I2 is 1,3,5 (where I2 = 2 integers apart). T and I don't always have to be there. if T is there, I doesn't have to be there. If T is there, I is always after.

If the cell shows 25;45;56;79, then 25 goes into 1 cell, 45 another etc.

The only combinations you will see are: 1;1T2;1T5I2. And the numbers will be positive integers potentially up to 10000.

There could be B2 to B20, and the semi colons could be 1000's of them.....

I'm thinking a loop to look at each character and if its a number, then make a string between the numbers until its broken by a T,I or ; -  However I'm stuck.

Image of what I'm after in Excel:

[image: what I'm after in Excel]

Comment: (1) The image is relatively illuminating, but please also *describe* the processing that you want done. (2) You say that the series specifications “don't always have `T` or `I`”. Can they have `I` but not `T`? If so, what would that mean? (3) Do you guarantee that no specification will ever have (a) `I` before `T`, (b) `I` or `T` more than once, (c) any character other than `I`, `T` and numbers, and will never (d) begin with a letter, (e) end with a letter, or (f) have `T` immediately followed by `I` with no number between? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) You show (in `B2` and `B3`) two series specifications, separated by semicolons. Will there always be *two* specifications, or can there be more? Is there a limit to the number that can appear? (5) If there is a maximum number of series specifications that can be concatenated, it might be possible to solve this with worksheet formulas instead of VBA. Have you considered that? What do you think about it? (6) What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (7) Shouldn’t `B13` be 4? … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Data in D8 has interval of 1 but others have 2 and also the same issue with A6:A9 ,, in this situation a common  code cant perform any  such act without criteria,, just  edit your question to give us more infos.

Comment: Hi Scott, (1) I essentially want a list of numbers with the corresponding data next to it. So 1T4 should be 1,2,3,4 in 4 cells, 1T5I2 is 1,3,5 (where I2 = 2 integers apart). T and I don't always have to be there. if T is there, I doesn't have to be there. If T is there, I is always after. (2) as in if the cell shows 25;45;56;79, then 25 goes into 1 cell, 45 another etc. (3) The only combinations you will see are: 1;1T2;1T5I2. And the numbers will be positive integers potentially up to 10000. (4) there could be B2 to B12, and the semi colons could be 1000's of them..... (cont'd)

Comment: (Cont'd).. So I'm thinking a loop to look at each character and if its a number, then make a string between the numbers until its broken by a T,I or ;

Comment: Apologies Scott, I read your edit comment last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro3 is multiple semicolon in one cell
Macro2 is for multiple inputs from B2 to B20
Copy & Paste this Macro with the Sheet and Run it:
[image]

```
Sub Macro3()
'
Dim Txt1, TxtL, Str(), Fruit, Txt As String
Dim x, n, Ff, Tt, Ii, r, i, L, Lx, ix As Integer

r = 12

For x = 2 To 20
Txt1 = Range("B" & x).Value
TxtL = Txt1
Fruit = Range("A" & x).Value
L = Len(Txt1) - Len(Replace(Txt1, ";", ""))
ReDim Str(L)
If Txt1 = "" Then Exit For

For Lx = 0 To L
ix = InStr(1, TxtL, ";")
If ix = 0 Then ix = Len(Txt1) + 1
Str(Lx) = Left(TxtL, ix - 1)
TxtL = Mid(TxtL, ix + 1, Len(Txt1))
Next Lx

For n = 0 To L
Txt = Str(n)
Ff = 0: Tt = 0: Ii = 1
Ff = Val(Txt)
If InStr(1, Txt, "T") > 0 Then Tt = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "T") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Tt = Ff
If InStr(1, Txt, "I") > 0 Then Ii = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "I") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Ii = 1
For i = Ff To Tt Step Ii
Range("D" & r).Value = i
Range("E" & r).Value = Fruit
r = r + 1
Next i
Next n
Next x

MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Macro2()
'
Dim Txt1, Str(4), Fruit, Txt As String
Dim x, n, Ff, Tt, Ii, r, i As Integer

r = 12
For x = 2 To 20
Txt1 = Range("B" & x).Value
Fruit = Range("A" & x).Value
If Txt1 = "" Then Exit For
Str(0) = Left(Txt1, InStr(1, Txt1, ";") - 1)
Str(1) = Mid(Txt1, InStr(1, Txt1, ";") + 1, Len(Txt1))

For n = 0 To 1
Txt = Str(n)
Ff = 0: Tt = 0: Ii = 1
Ff = Val(Txt)
If InStr(1, Txt, "T") > 0 Then Tt = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "T") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Tt = Ff
If InStr(1, Txt, "I") > 0 Then Ii = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "I") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Ii = 1
For i = Ff To Tt Step Ii
Range("D" & r).Value = i
Range("E" & r).Value = Fruit
r = r + 1
Next i
Next n
Next x
MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Macro1()    
'    
Dim Txt1, Txt2, Str(4), Txt As String    
Dim n, Ff, Tt, Ii, r, i As Integer

Txt1 = Range("B2").Value    
Txt2 = Range("B3").Value    
Str(0) = Left(Txt1, InStr(1, Txt1, ";") - 1)    
Str(1) = Mid(Txt1, InStr(1, Txt1, ";") + 1, Len(Txt1))    
Str(2) = Left(Txt2, InStr(1, Txt2, ";") - 1)    
Str(3) = Mid(Txt2, InStr(1, Txt2, ";") + 1, Len(Txt2))    

r = 12    
For n = 0 To 3    
Txt = Str(n)    
Ff = 0: Tt = 0: Ii = 1    
Ff = Val(Txt)    
If InStr(1, Txt, "T") > 0 Then Tt = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "T") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Tt = Ff    
If InStr(1, Txt, "I") > 0 Then Ii = Val(Mid(Txt, InStr(1, Txt, "I") + 1, Len(Txt))) Else Ii = 1    
For i = Ff To Tt Step Ii    
Range("B" & r).Value = i    
If i >= 1 And i <= 10 Then Range("C" & r).Value = "Apple"    
If i > 10 Then Range("C" & r).Value = "Mango"    
r = r + 1    
Next i
Next n

MsgBox "done"    
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91456/discussion-on-answer-by-ahmed-alsayed-excel-vba-for-pulling-apart-text-from-a-fe).